# Exclusão de arquivos de multi upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload

Tenho o seguinte código que inclui arquivos para upload:

#### HTML

```
<p>Utilize a tecla <b>Ctrl</b> para selecionar mais de um arquivo.</p>
<div id="multiple_upload">
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="uploadChange" />
    <div id="message">Selecionar fotos</div>
    <input type="button" id="botao" value="Upload" />
   <div id="lista">
   </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
p, ol, #message {
     font-family:'Open Sans';
}
#multiple_upload {
      position:relative;
}
#uploadChange {
      position:absolute;
      top:2px;
      left:0;
      opacity:0.01;
      border:none;
      width:355px;
      padding:10px;
      z-index:1;
      cursor:pointer
}
#message {
      border:2px solid #ccc;
      background:#fff;
      padding:10px;
      width:250px;
      float:left;
      margin:4px;
      overflow:hidden;
      color: #333
}
#botao {
      border:1px solid #ff7b00;
      background:#ff7b00;
      color:#ffffff;
      font-family:'Open Sans';
      font-size:15px;
      font-weight:bold;
      padding:12px 28px;
      margin:4px 8px;
}
#multiple_upload:hover > #botao {
      background:#662f00;
      border-color:#662f00;
} 
#lista ol {
      margin-left: -16px; 
}
#lista ol li {
     border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
     padding:10px;
    display:block;
    clear:left;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
#lista ol li.item_grey{
     background:#f9f9f9;
}
a.remove {
     text-decoration:none;
     color:#ff7b00;   
     display:block;
     font-size: 16px;
     width:20px;
     float:right;
     font-weight:bold;
}
a.remove:hover {
    color:red;
}
img.item {


}
img.item {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.box-images {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border:1px solid #eee;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    /* Centralizando imagens */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px 20px 0;
}
```

#### JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function(){
    $('#uploadChange').on('change',function() {
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var totalFiles = $(this).get(0).files.length;
        if(totalFiles == 0) {
          $('#message').text('Selecionar fotos' );
        }
        if ( totalFiles > 1) {
            $('#message').text( totalFiles+' arquivos selecionados' );
        } else {
            $('#message').text( totalFiles+' arquivo selecionado' );
        }
           var htm='<ol>';
         for (var i=0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
             var c = (i % 2 == 0) ? 'item_white' : 'item_grey';
             var arquivo = $(this).get(0).files[i];
             var fileV = new readFileView(arquivo, i);
             htm += '<li class="'+c+'"><div class="box-images"><img class="item" data-img="'+i+'" border="0"></div><span>'+arquivo.name+'</span><a href="javascript:removeFile('+i+',\''+id+'\')" class="remove">x</a></li>'+"\n";
         }
        htm += '</ol>';
           $('#lista').html(htm);

    });

});

function readFileView(file, i) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function (e) {
       $('[data-img="'+i+'"]').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function removeFile(item, id) {
    var el = $('#'+id);
  if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja remover este item?')) {
            el.get(0).files.splice(item, 1);
             el.val(el.get(0).files);
  }
}
```

Exemplo no [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/yrvyf2gn/20/)

Preciso fazer com que a exclusão de arquivos funcione, como poderia resolver isso, tem alguma forma de fazer usando a função [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)?

Answer (score -1):

Na função `removeFile`, pegue o elemento em questão assim: `var el = $('img[data-img="'+item+'"]');`

Para excluí-lo, pegue o `closet("li")`, ou seja, o elemento `<li>` mais próximo dele.

```
function removeFile(item, id) {
    var el = $('img[data-img="'+item+'"]');

  if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja remover este item?')) {
       teste3.closest("li").remove();             
  }
}
```

Depois disso, se quiser atualizar a quantidade de arquivos selecionados na div `$('#message')`, pegue o valor atual e diminua 1:

```
var textoQtdArquivosAtuais = $('#message').text();
var qtdArquivosSelecionados = parseInt(textoQtdArquivosAtuais.substring(0, parseInt(textoQtdArquivosAtuais.indexOf(' arquivo')))); 
qtdArquivosSelecionados = qtdArquivosSelecionados - 1;
if (qtdArquivosSelecionados > 1) 
    $('#message').text(qtdArquivosSelecionados + " arquivos selecionados");
else
    $('#message').text(qtdArquivosSelecionados + " arquivo selecionados");
```

No fim das contas, sua função fica assim:

```
function removeFile(item, id) {
    var el = $('img[data-img="'+item+'"]');
    var textoQtdArquivosAtuais = $('#message').text();
    var qtdArquivosSelecionados = parseInt(textoQtdArquivosAtuais.substring(0, parseInt(textoQtdArquivosAtuais.indexOf(' arquivo')))); 

  if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja remover este item?')) {
        el.closest("li").remove();  
      qtdArquivosSelecionados = qtdArquivosSelecionados -1;
      //Alterando label com quantidade de arquivos selecionados..  

        if(qtdArquivosSelecionados == 0) {
          $('#message').text('Selecionar fotos' );
        } else {
             if (qtdArquivosSelecionados > 1) {
                 $('#message').text( qtdArquivosSelecionados+' arquivos selecionados' );
             } else {
                 $('#message').text( qtdArquivosSelecionados+' arquivo selecionado' );
             }
        }
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tretaa/yrvyf2gn/52/)

Comment: Só tem um problema, não está removendo do input, isso eu já tinha feito: https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/yrvyf2gn/

Comment: a lista do input file do html 5 é `readonly`, não dá pra manipular... trabalha em cima do array da `div lista` que você pode fazer o que quiser :)